An outer regularity property of finite Borel measures over Hausdorff topological spaces
Is it true that for any Hausdorff topological space $X$, any finite Borel measure $\mu$ over $X$ is outer regular in the sense that for any compact subset $K$ of $X$ and any real $\delta>0$ there is an open set $U$ containing $K$ such that $\mu(U\setminus K)<\delta$?

This is not true. Here is a counterexample, which appears in Exercise 15 of Section 7.2 in Folland (1999, pages 220–221).
Let $\Omega$ be the set of countable ordinals, $\omega_1$ the first uncountable ordinal, and $\Omega^*=\Omega\cup\{\omega_1\}$. Endow $\Omega^*$ with the order topology. Then, $\Omega^*$ becomes a compact (!) Hausdorff space. Define a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\Omega^*$ that assigns to each Borel set $E\subseteq X$ the value of $1$ if $E\cup\{\omega_1\}$ contains an uncountable closed set and the value of $0$ otherwise. Then, $\mu$ is a finite measure satisfying $\mu(\{\omega_1\})=0$ but $\mu(U)=1$ for every open set $U$ containing $\omega_1$. Therefore, $\mu$ is not outer regular.
The answer to your question is affirmative, however, if $X$ is assumed to be, in addition, locally compact and has the property that every open set is a countable union of compact sets. See Theorem 7.8 in Folland (1999, page 217).

Thank you for the answer. Can you explain in detail why this $\mu$ is a measure?

@IosifPinelis Hints (from the exercise in Folland, 1999): (i) Any set $E\subseteq\Omega$ is uncountable if and only if the intersection of $E$ and the “interval” $(x,\omega_1)$ is not empty for any $x\in\Omega$. (ii) The intersection of countably many uncountable closed sets is uncountable. (iii) Let $\mathcal E$ denote the family of those sets $E\subseteq\Omega^*$ for which either $E\cup{\omega_1}$ or $E^{\textsf c}\cup{\omega_1}$ contains an uncountable closed set. Note that $\mathcal E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains the open sets. Therefore, every Borel set is in $\mathcal E$.

Can you just explain (ii), in detail? Of course, it is enough to just show that the intersection of two uncountable closed sets is of cardinality $>1$.

@IosifPinelis Folland gives the following additional hint: Let $E_n\subseteq\Omega^*$ be an uncountable closed set for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Suppose that $(x_j){j\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence in $\Omega$ such that (i) it is increasing; and (ii) $E_n$ contains infinitely many members of the sequence $(x_j){j\in\mathbb N}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, the sequence $(x_j){j\in\mathbb N}$ converges and its limit is in $\bigcap{n\in\mathbb N}E_n$.

@IosifPinelis Given this hint, fix any $x\in\Omega$. Using the uncountability of $E_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$, construct a sequence inductively such that $x<x_1<x_2<\cdots$ and $$\begin{array}{cccc}x_1\in E_1&&&\x_2\in E_1&x_3\in E_2&&\x_4\in E_1&x_5\in E_2&x_6\in E_3&&\x_7\in E_1&x_8\in E_2&x_9\in E_3&x_{10}\in E_4\end{array}$$ and so forth. By construction, $E_n$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Then, the limit of the sequence is in the intersection of $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}E_n$ and the “interval” $(x,\omega_1)$.

Thank you for these details.
